# Paramaterized queries using OracleDataAdapter

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-mvc-3, oracle

I'm currently using a Controller class in conjunction with a data access layer class (UserDAL class) in order to make changes to a database. However I am aware that my code is vunerable as I am not using parameterised queries.

I've seen from excamples how to use the queries using command objects. However I am using an OracleDataAdapter which seems to behave a little bit differently. It is also in a different class from the actual values which would be parameterised as can be seen here in the following sections of code:

Controller code, where the three strings are filled from user inputted fields:

```
string usrName = mod.UserName;
string role = mod.Role;
string mod.actvInd;


string sql = "UPDATE LD_USER_ROLE" + " SET USERNAME='" + usrName + "', ROLE='" + role + "', ACTIVE_IND='" + actvInd  + "' WHERE USER_ROLE_ID=" + id + "";

UserRoleDAL udl = new UserRoleDAL();
            udl.ExecuteQuery(sql);
```

UserDAL class:

```
public class UserRoleDAL
{

    private OracleConnection conn;

    public UserRoleDAL()
    {
         string oradb = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db_dbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        conn = new OracleConnection(oradb);
    }


    public void ExecuteQuery(string sql)
    {
        conn.Open();

        OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(ds);

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

How do I use paramterized queries with the OracleDataAdapter object and will I have to merge the above classes or even pass the fields into the UserRoleDAL object in order to do this?

Comment: [OracleDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oracledataadapter(v=vs.100).aspx) is now obsolete, why are you still using it ?

Comment: @habib What should I be using instead? I'm connecting to an Oracle db using ODP.Net

Comment: you may use an OracleCommand with parameters and use that with OracleDataAdapter. I am not sure about the replacement of OracleDataAdapter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use OracleDataAdapter with OracleCommand like this:

```
public void ExecuteQuery(string usrName, string role, string activeation, int userId)
{
  string sql = "UPDATE LD_USER_ROLE SET USERNAME=:usrName, ROLE=:role, ACTIVE_IND=:actvInd  WHERE USER_ROLE_ID=:id";

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.BindByName = true;

    cmd.Parameters.Add("usrName", usrName);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("role", role);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("actvInd", activeation);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("id", userId);

    OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);
}
```